# iterate nested list in json msg by cql stream analytics

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, cql, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I have a json msg coming from iotHub like:

```
{
    "deviceId": "abc",
    "topic": "data",
    "data": {
        "varname1": [{
            "t": "timestamp1",
            "v": "value1",
            "f": "respondFrame1"
        },
        {
            "t": "timestamp2",
            "v": "value2",
            "f": "respondFrame2"
        }],
        "varname2": [{
            "t": "timestamp1",
            "v": "value1",
            "f": "respondFrame1"
        },
        {
            "t": "timestamp2",
            "v": "value2",
            "f": "respondFrame2"
        }]
    }
}
```

and want to store this by azure stream analytics job into a transact sql like this:

```
ID   |   deviceId |  varname  |  timestamp  |  respondFrame  | value
-----+------------+-----------+-------------+----------------+--------
1    |   abc      |  varname1 |  timestamp1 |  respondFrame1 | value1
2    |   abc      |  varname1 |  timestamp2 |  respondFrame2 | value2
3    |   abc      |  varname2 |  timestamp1 |  respondFrame1 | value1
4    |   abc      |  varname2 |  timestamp2 |  respondFrame2 | value2
```

does anaybody knwo how to handle this stacked iterations and combine it (cross apply)?

something like this "phantomCode":

```
deviceId = msg.deviceId
for d in msg.data:
    for key in d:
        varname = key.name
        timestamp = key[varname].t
        frame = key[varname].f
        value = key[varname].v
```

**UPDATE** regarding to JS Azure answer:

with the code

```
WITH datalist AS
(
    SELECT   
        iotHubAlias.deviceId,  
        data.PropertyName as varname,  
        data.PropertyValue as arrayData 
    FROM [iotHub] as iotHubAlias  
    CROSS APPLY GetRecordProperties(iotHubAlias.data) AS data
    WHERE iotHubAlias.topic = 'data'
)
SELECT
    datalist.deviceId,
    datalist.varname,
    arrayElement.ArrayValue.t as [timestamp],
    arrayElement.ArrayValue.f as respondFrame,
    arrayElement.ArrayValue.v as value
INTO [temporary]
FROM datalist 
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(datalist.arrayData) AS arrayElement
```

I always get an error:

```
{
    "channels": "Operation",
    "correlationId": "f9d4437b-707e-4892-a37b-8ad721eb1bb2",
    "description": "",
    "eventDataId": "ef5a5f2b-8c2f-49c2-91f0-16213aaa959d",
    "eventName": {
        "value": "streamingNode0",
        "localizedValue": "streamingNode0"
    },
    "category": {
        "value": "Administrative",
        "localizedValue": "Administrative"
    },
    "eventTimestamp": "2018-08-21T18:23:39.1804989Z",
    "id": "/subscriptions/46cd2f8f-b46b-4428-8f7b-c7d942ff745d/resourceGroups/fieldtest/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/streamAnalytics4fieldtest/events/ef5a5f2b-8c2f-49c2-91f0-16213aaa959d/ticks/636704726191804989",
    "level": "Error",
    "operationId": "7a38a957-1a51-4da1-a679-eae1c7e3a65b",
    "operationName": {
        "value": "Process Events: Processing events Runtime Error",
        "localizedValue": "Process Events: Processing events Runtime Error"
    },
    "resourceGroupName": "fieldtest",
    "resourceProviderName": {
        "value": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics",
        "localizedValue": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics"
    },
    "resourceType": {
        "value": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs",
        "localizedValue": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs"
    },
    "resourceId": "/subscriptions/46cd2f8f-b46b-4428-8f7b-c7d942ff745d/resourceGroups/fieldtest/providers/Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/streamAnalytics4fieldtest",
    "status": {
        "value": "Failed",
        "localizedValue": "Failed"
    },
    "subStatus": {
        "value": "",
        "localizedValue": ""
    },
    "submissionTimestamp": "2018-08-21T18:24:34.0981187Z",
    "subscriptionId": "46cd2f8f-b46b-4428-8f7b-c7d942ff745d",
    "properties": {
        "Message Time": "2018-08-21 18:23:39Z",
        "Error": "- Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EventProcessing.RuntimeTypes.ValueArray' to type 'Microsoft.EventProcessing.RuntimeTypes.IRecord'.\r\n",
        "Message": "Runtime exception occurred while processing events, - Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EventProcessing.RuntimeTypes.ValueArray' to type 'Microsoft.EventProcessing.RuntimeTypes.IRecord'.\r\n, : OutputSourceAlias:temporary;",
        "Type": "SqlRuntimeError",
        "Correlation ID": "f9d4437b-707e-4892-a37b-8ad721eb1bb2"
    },
    "relatedEvents": []
}
```

and here an example of a real json msg coming from a device:

```
{
    "topic": "data",
    "data": {
        "ExternalFlowTemperatureSensor": [{
            "t": "2018-08-22T11:00:11.955381",
            "v": 16.64103,
            "f": "Q6ES8KJIN1NX2DRGH36RX1WDT"
        }],
        "AdaStartsP2": [{
            "t": "2018-08-22T11:00:12.863383",
            "v": 382.363138,
            "f": "9IY7B4DFBAMOLH3GNKRUNUQNUX"
        },
        {
            "t": "2018-08-22T11:00:54.172501",
            "v": 104.0,
            "f": "IUJMP20CYQK60B"
        }],
        "s_DriftData[4].c32_ZeitLetzterTest": [{
            "t": "2018-08-22T11:01:01.829568",
            "v": 348.2916,
            "f": "MMTPWQVLL02CA"
        }]
    },
    "deviceId": "test_3c27db"
}
```

and (to have it complete) the creation code for the sql table:

```
create table temporary (
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    deviceId nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    timestamp datetime NOT NULL,
    varname nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    value float,
    respondFrame nvarchar(50)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

the following query will give you the expected output

```
WITH step1 AS
(
SELECT   
    event.deviceID,  
    data.PropertyName as varname,  
    data.PropertyValue as arrayData 
FROM blobtest as event  
CROSS APPLY GetRecordProperties(event.data) AS data  
)
SELECT
    event.deviceId,
    event.varname,
    arrayElement.ArrayValue.t  as [timestamp],
    arrayElement.ArrayValue.f as frame,
    arrayElement.ArrayValue.v as value
FROM step1 as event  
CROSS APPLY GetArrayElements(event.arrayData) AS arrayElement
```

You can find more info about JSON parsing on our documentation page "[Parse JSON and Avro data in Azure Stream Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-parsing-json)"

Let me know if you have any other question.

JS (Azure Stream Analytics)

Comment: thanks for your answer! But when I do like your code I always get a runtimeError. Please see the update-part in my question above. Do you have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: Hi again, sorry to hear it's not working. Since it works with the sample posted in your initial question, I'm thinking you may have message that are not compliant to that schema. Can you use the "sample" feature in the input blade to download some actual inputs? Then we can look what happens, and filter out messages not following your expected schema.

Comment: ok thanks. Please look into my question: I added an example of a real msg which is sent by a device to iotHub

Comment: I tried your exact query with a SQL Database using the same schema you suggested and it works. My theory is you have some events that don't fit the schema. We can try to make the query more schema independent with some TRY_CAST. To confirm this theory, is it possible to collect a longer sample of data and send it to us? You can then sent it to our team: askasa@microsoft,com